# Zend framework 3 form issue with binding entities that use return type hinting

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-framework3, php-7.3

As I'm upgrading my application to PHP 7.3, I decided to add return type hinting to my entities methods.
An example would be something like this:

```
class User {
    private $username;
    public method getUsername(): string { return $this->username}
}
```

I use this entity in a form (to create users) where I bind it like so:

```
$user = new User();
$form->bind($user);
$form->setData($data);
```

However I get this error which is caused by the hydrator (I'm using the DoctrineObject hydrator)

```
Return value of Admin\Entity\Auth\User::getUsername() must be of the type string, null returned
#0 ...\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-module\src\DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject.php(220): Admin\Entity\Auth\User->getUsername()
#1 ...\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-module\src\DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject.php(116): DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject->extractByValue(Object(Admin\Entity\Auth\User))
#2 ...\vendor\zendframework\zend-form\src\Fieldset.php(650): DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject->extract(Object(Admin\Entity\Auth\User))
...
```

From the snippet above it's obvious that it's calling the getUsername method on an "empty" object, which makes it return null and throw the exception.
This is not logically correct as the entity is supposed to have a username so marking it as nullable (?string) is not correct.

Is there any better solution to this? Because making every single method return type nullable seems like a hack that defeats the purpose.

Comment: private $username = ''; will take care of the problem.

Comment: For some reason (not entirely sure as to why), Doctrine creates instances of Entity objects and immediately calls the getters. To fix either follow what Cerad said or make the getters nullable (`function getUsername(): ?string`)

Comment: @rkeet No, Doctrine does not call the getters.  It is $form->bind which calls the getters.  In fact, even when loading and unloading to and from the database, Doctrine does not use getters or setters.  It access the properties directly using reflection.

Comment: thanks for your help. I don't really want to put empty defaults to all the attributes of my classes, I know it's a solution but seems hacky as well. The method that uses the getters is from Doctrine, you can see it here https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineModule/Stdlib/Hydrator/DoctrineObject.php#L201

Comment: vendor\zendframework\zend-form\src\Fieldset.php(650) strongly implies that it is the form component initiating the call.  And why would setting initial values for properties feel hacky?  If a property is not nullable then initializing it to null (the php default) is what is hacky.

Comment: Could you try to use `Zend\Hydrator\ReflectionHydrator` ? It should has access to private / protected fields ?